# azure time stamp filtering picks wrong dates

Tags: azure, timestamp, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-table-storage

I am using azure table storage and trying to filter records only for one particular day.

```
datetime filterDate = '3/29/2016 12:00:00 AM'
```

I tried the below query but it pulls records for **both 29th and 30th**. what may be the issue?

```
 var queryToday = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, filterDate);
            var querySelectedDate = TableQuery.CombineFilters(queryToday, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThan, filterDate.AddDays(1)));
```

I debugged and found the filter string as

```
(Timestamp ge datetime'2016-03-29T07:00:00.0000000Z') and (Timestamp lt datetime'2016-03-30T07:00:00.0000000Z')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Time Zone issue. You probably want to search between midnight 3/29 and midnight 3/30, but instead it's searching between 7am 3/29 and 7am 3/30.

Do you live in either a UTC-7 time zone (like MDT) or a UTC +7 timezone (like ETC)?  The api is most likely trying to compensate for the timezone you/your site is in and the timezone it assumes the Timestamp is in (which is probably UTC time)

Comment: very interesting. you mean .AddHours(-7) ?

Does that mean

var queryToday = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, filterDate.AddHours(-7));
            var querySelectedDate = TableQuery.CombineFilters(queryToday, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThan, filterDate.AddDays(1).AddHours(-7)));

Answer (score 2):

Please convert the date time to UTC firstly.

```
var universalFilterDate = filterDate.ToUniversalTime();
var queryToday = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, universalFilterDate);
var querySelectedDate = TableQuery.CombineFilters(queryToday, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThan, universalFilterDate.AddDays(1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Windows Azure Storage 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and you can use Linq query so that you don't have to convert to UTC :

```
// initialize the filterdate
var filterDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2016 12:00:00 AM");

// Get the cloudtable ...
var cloudTable = GetCloudTable();

// Create a query: in this example I use the DynamicTableEntity class
var query = cloudTable.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
    .Where(d => d.Timestamp > filterDate);

var result = query.ToList();
```

If you inspect the `query.FilterString` property, you can see that the datetime has been converted to a UTC datetime :

> "Timestamp gt datetime'2016-01-31T11:00:00Z'"